# Probability of getting a green ball

Tags: probability

Suppose there is an urn and it contains $2n$balls of which $n$ balls are colored red and the rest are colored green. We roll an unbiased $n$ sided die.The faces of the die are numbered from $1$ to $n$. Suppose the number shown  by the face of the die is some random variable $r$. Then we pick $r$ number of balls from the urn and place them in a bag. Then we randomly pick any ball from the bag. What is the probability that the ball is green?

I got the answer as $1/2$. Please help me verify my answer. I am not looking for the solution. Thank you.

Clarification - We need to find the total probability for all such $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple answer could be: if $p_{green}$ is the probability that you pick a green ball, then $p_{green}$ is also the probability that you pick a red one (as there is the same amount of them in the urn); furthermore the ball picked at last can be red or green, so $p_{red}+p_{green} = 1 \Rightarrow p_{green}=p_{red} = \frac12$

Comment: Is there another more rigorous proof of the above result that the two probabilities are equal ?

Comment: $p_{red}=p_{green}$ just because, once you've made a reasoning to find $p_{red}$, you can make the same reasoning for the green balls! and since there are the same number of green balls and of red ones, the probability will be the same!

Comment: The symmetry argument is fully rigorous.

Comment: yes! of course! the symmetry! but, only because the number of green balls is the same of the red ones